do we need to download any AI model in local to run something local?
Ihave litlle knowledge of python but heavily on javascript so trying to use and learn using javascript and uring trying hand in AI and found bolt.dit have a public repo; so clone and try to run it but it have multiple options; to add API keys of various vendors and model but even after setting the API keys; it runs and send APi request to https://localhost:1234 while project running on 5173 port
so my question is what to run on localhost:1234 ? do I need to download Ollama AI LLMs in my system and configure somewhere? can I run eveything locally using those LLMS , does those are heavy in size, do we have any smaller one? bolt's documentation lack this thing and asked in community too and they sugegst to watch video and which also have half information.
I am running on ubuntu 24.04 in desktop sowant to learn becuse Ollama failed issue also coming.
Bold techical issue has been raised  seprately , that is not my question.
my question is how can one from node.js background, use/download/build LLM locallay, not just using some API keys ?
